# Cast error when specifying NoTracking MergeOption in EF 5

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using EntityFramework 5.0.0 in a database-first design, and trying to specify the NoTracking MergeOption on some queries over very large result sets, using the method explained at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2010/01/12/ef-merge-options-and-compiled-queries.aspx

My code looks something like:

```
using (var dbContext = Utility.GetDataContext()) {
    IQueryable<EntityTypeA> entitiesQry = dbContext.EntitiesA.Where(x => (x.field== this.Property));
    ((System.Data.Object.ObjectQuery)entitiesQry).MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;

    foreach (var rec in entitiesQry) {
        // do things...
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting a runtime exception when  casting entitiesQry:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Namespace.EntityTypeA]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.

Given the age of that article and the differing namespaces, I'm guessing this is something that changed between EF 4 and EF 5? But I can't find any more appropriate way to specify the MergeOption... Any help would be appreciated.

To be clear: my code runs perfectly fine without the line setting the MergeOption, but given that my data set is in the millions of records, I'm having "memory issues".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `ObjectQuery` then you need to get the underlying `ObjectContext` and formulate your query from there.

```
ObjectQuery<EntitiesA> objQuery = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx)
   .ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<EntitiesA>()
   .Where(x => x.field == this.Property);
```

If you want a no tracking query using the `DbContext` API then you can use `AsNoTracking()`:

```
IQueryable<EntityTypeA> entitiesQry = dbContext.EntitiesA.AsNoTracking()
                           .Where(x => x.field== this.Property);
```